# Phone number format isnot validation in Lightning Input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In Lightning Input,it validates email format

Code for Email:

```
<lightning:input label="Email " value="{!v.account.email}" required="true" type="email"/>
```

But I have tried below code for phone number,itsnot validating phone number format.We can easily enter text also

```
<lightning:input label="phone" value="{!v.account.phone}" required="true" type="phone"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

list of available values of `type` attribute are listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example) as examples, and there is no `phone` type

change type to `tel` in order to have phone validation, also populate regex pattern as `pattern`

```
<lightning:input type="tel" label="phone" value="{!v.account.phone}" required="true" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"/>
```

Comment: why its not accepting this pattern :12344567891...what kind of format it will accept?..can you please explain the pattern once.This pattern 1234-456-7891?

Comment: @AnnappaPH this regular expression. to read more about it you can check [it](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)